# Does $(x_1 + \cdots +x_n)^n \geq n(x_1 \cdots x_n)^{1/n}$ hold true for positive $x_i$?

Tags: inequality

Suppose $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ are strictly positive real numbers. Then

$(x_1 + \cdots +x_n)^n \geq n(x_1 \cdots x_n)^{1/n}$

Is this statement true? If not, can you provide a counter example?

Comment: I think the statement is FALSE..

Comment: Take, $x_1=1,x_2=2$. Then $\sqrt 3>2\sqrt 2$ , which is absurd.

Comment: It is false as the counter examples peole gave you prove. But the inequality $x_1+\cdots+x_n\ge n(x_1\cdots x_n)^\frac{1}{n}$ is correct. It's the AM-GM inequality (Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just consider e.g. $n=2$ and $x_1 = x_2 = \frac{1}{4}$.

Note that the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) is of a very similar form; it states that

$$x_1+\ldots+x_n \geq n (x_1 \cdots x_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}.$$

This means in particular that the inequality from the OP holds true whenever $x_1+\ldots+x_n \geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Put $x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_n=x$. The inequality becomes $(nx)^{n-1}\ge1$, which is not generally true.

Answer (score 0):

It's true, when $x_1+\cdots+x_n>1$, because in that case, it follows from what is known as the [Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), which states that

$$x_1 + \cdots +x_n \geq n(x_1 \cdots x_n)^{1/n},$$

and when $\sum x_i > 1$, you have $(x_1 + \cdots +x_n)^n \geq x_1 + \cdots +x_n$.